# Is it okay for employers to "reuse" Jobs listings?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow-jobs

I've been spending a good bit of time on Careers recently, and I've noticed a trend: Old listings that I've inquired about or applied for will show up at the top of Most Recent, along with their status icons, but with completely new titles and text.

I understand that SO charges fees per listing, and it appears that some employers are taking the opportunity to rewrite existing entries instead of opening new ones. While it doesn't matter to me personally whether SO approves of or frowns on this practice from a billing standpoint, it's both annoying and disadvantageous to me, since a new similar listing may also be something that I want to ask about or apply for, but Careers notes that I've already applied for "that" listing, and the button is replaced with the good-luck banner.

Does SO have a particular policy about whether new listings in the guise of edits are permissible? If they're not, what do we do when noticing one? If they are, how could we mitigate the impedance to job seekers?

Comment: People were employed but didn't work out?

Comment: @Noodles In these cases, companies are rewriting the listings for substantially different jobs.

Comment: This would happen in our company, too. Because the HR department has to have new entries approved by the director, it's easier for them to change existing entries rather than go through the whole process of asking for a new one. They do that on the internal website, StepStone and Monster and they would probably do the same on Careers. - Changing internal processes seems impossible.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

We don't have a policy against employers' reusing job listings, but we agree it's confusing and would prefer people didn't do it.  We would prefer that an employer ends one job listing and creates a new one, which they can do without additional cost.  Unfortunately, right now, we make it difficult for employers to do what we — and you — would like.

Instead of implementing more rules, we're trying to make it easier for employers to do the right thing.  To that end, I've been working on a system that allows employers to copy and then modify a previous listing rather than editing it in place.  This feature still needs some testing, but we hope to have it rolled out soon.  The new feature may not completely solve the problem, but we hope it will make the user experience better for both candidates and employers.

Comment: I have an ideal test case. Stack Overflow Careers is looking for a Product manager. [They recently reposted their listing.](http://stackoverflow.com/jobs/118887/product-manager-stack-overflow-careers-stack-overflow) Maybe you can reach out to someone there. ;)